# how to calculate market value weighted price in stata

Tags: stata

I have a example stata file in this link: http://yunpan.cn/cLVEmBxX6RZYZ  Password:90fa

I want to caluculate the market value weighted price in Stata and I have already thought about some codes, but I still do not know how to get my result.
This is my code.

```
    egen company=group(ISINnumber)

sum company

local c=r(max)

gen PM=Aprice*Amarketvalue

forvalues i=1/1303 {
forvalues n=1/`c'  {
local PMprice`n'`i'=PM if company==`n' & week==`i'
}
}
```

Comment: Did you know there is a special site for statistics? http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's better to post example data with the question. External sources (a) oblige posters to do more work (b) may not remain accessible indefinitely. That's for your future questions: as flagged, weighted market prices are already an example in another thread.

Comment: @hgoebl This question would be judged off-topic on Cross Validated given its exclusive focus on Stata code.